# Can API.AI take input other than JSON?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I'm new in Dialogflow and I have a report in the XML format, which is generated from my internal application. I want to use that XML file data as an input for my Agent (created in Dialogflow). Is it possible?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "input for my Agent"? What are you trying to do with the XML file data and what do you expect the result to be?

Comment: Actually, I performed an action from my webhook, then that webhook server provided me data in the XML format.
Now I want to use that data as an input for performing some actions in API.Ai and want to take relevant response.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm still not clear about what the process flow here is. Are you saying that you have a Dialogflow webhook fulfillment, and that is calling something that generates XML? Or are you trying to do this without additional webhooks?

Comment: Sry for my bad English, you have got my point. I have a Dialogflow webhook fulfillment, and that is calling my Internal application and it generates an XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. What you would do in your fulfillment webhook is something like the following:

1. Determine which Intent was called and any parameters you may need to make the call to your internal application.
2. Call your internal application using REST or something similar. If you're using something like node.js, you'll need to do this as an asynchronous function with Promises.
3. When you get the results back, present them as part of your response.